# When is C++ Class Constructor called with pointer?

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, smart-pointers

I don't have deep knowledge about c++.
I've implemented the smart pointer to prevent the issues caused by raw pointer. (memory leak)
The code is following for the smart pointer.

```
#ifndef SMARTPOINTER
#define SMARTPOINTER
class RC
{
    private:
    int count; // Reference count
    public:
    RC(){            count = 0;        }
    void AddRef()
    {
        // Increment the reference count
        count++;
    }
    int Release()
    {
        // Decrement the reference count and
        // return the reference count.
        if(count==0) return 0;
        return --count;
    }
};

template < typename T > class SP
{
private:
    T*    pData;       // pointer
    RC* reference; // Reference count
public:
    SP() : pData(0), reference(0)
    {
        // Create a new reference
        reference = new RC();
        // Increment the reference count
        reference->AddRef();
    }
    SP(T* pValue) : pData(pValue), reference(0)
    {
        // Create a new reference
        reference = new RC();
        // Increment the reference count
        reference->AddRef();
    }
    SP(const SP<T>& sp) : pData(sp.pData), reference(sp.reference)
    {
        // Copy constructor
        // Copy the data and reference pointer
        // and increment the reference count
        reference->AddRef();
    }
    ~SP()
    {
        // Destructor
        // Decrement the reference count
        // if reference become zero delete the data
        if(reference->Release() == 0)
        {
            delete pData;
            delete reference;
        }
    }
    T& operator* ()
    {
        return *pData;
    }
    T* operator-> ()
    {
        return pData;
    }
    SP<T>& operator = (const SP<T>& sp)
    {
        // Assignment operator
        if (this != &sp) // Avoid self assignment
        {
            // Decrement the old reference count
            // if reference become zero delete the old data
            if(reference->Release() == 0)
            {
                delete pData;
                delete reference;
            }

            // Copy the data and reference pointer
            // and increment the reference count
            pData = sp.pData;
            reference = sp.reference;
            reference->AddRef();
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
#endif // SMARTPOINTER
```

My question is following..
When using this smart pointer class as below

```
 SP<MyObject> ptrObject;  //MyObject class is the custom class.
 MyObject *ptr = new MyObject;
 ptrObject = ptr;  //This invokes the SP(T *) constructor.. why?
                   //Though operator = ( T*) is not defined.
```

At this time,though the `operator=(T*)` function is not defined, why is the constructor of the smart pointer,SP(T* pValue) ,  called?
I thought that the constructor is called when the class object is created.
Please explain this,  thanks.

Comment: Please explain the C tag.

Comment: Read about [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

Comment: reinventing the wheel is not recommended, try `std::shared_ptr` for example

Comment: @sp2danny Thought true for prouduction code, it might be useful for learning C++ a lot.

Comment: std::shared_ptr is not provided in c++. I think this is provided from c++11

Comment: @AndrewLi C++11 is the version that was validated seven years ago. We're at C++17 now. C++98 (what you call "C++") is obsolete.

Comment: @Quentin, I develops the app in qt 5.11 in ubuntu16.04. But it says the std::shared_ptr is not member function of std, though I've added header <memory>

Comment: @AndrewLi IIRC that means you're using the system's GCC 5 compiler, which has full support for C++14 once you enable it. That's good enough, but definitely stay away from C++98: C++11 has brought a *huge* paradigm shift and the two version hardly look like the same language.

Comment: @AndrewLi _"`std::shared_ptr` is not member function of `std`"_. `shared_ptr` is not a member function, it's a class. Maybe, you need to enable C++11 by using `-std=c++11` compiler flag.

Comment: @AndrewLi; Asuming you are using QtCreator, you need to add `CONFIG += c++11` to your project file. https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_C%2B%2B11_in_your_Qt_Projects

Comment: @AndrewLi and `#include <memory>`

Comment: @Caleth , Thanks a lot , I've learned from you, and thanks to everyone.

Comment: @Caleth, std::shared_ptr could be used like this std::shared_ptr<QList<MyClass> > ptr;    ptr= new QList<MyClass>; ?

Comment: It can be. You should see if `unique_ptr` would fit better. Also note that `QList` isn't a good default container. `std::vector` (with `#include <vector>`) is a much better default choice for container

Comment: @Caleth, but the code ptr = new QList<MyClass> gives an error;  no match operator = (opened types are std::shared_ptr<QList<Myclass> > and QList<Myclass> *

Comment: @AndrewLi writing your own reference-counted pointer that is thread-safe is not that easy. Even if you didn't have access to std::shared_ptr you said that you're writing a Qt app, Qt has QSharedPointer.

Comment: @PeterT QPointer,QSharedPointer is suitable for only QObject class.

Comment: @AndrewLi there is no such restriction for QSharedPointer, it's even used for a non QObject derived class in one of [the official examples](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/examples/quick/scenegraph/sgengine/window.h.html)

Comment: @PeterT , thanks , but those inherits QOjbect, while QList does not. You could try ..

Comment: @AndrewLi what? The definition for `Item` in that example [is here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/examples/quick/scenegraph/sgengine/window.cpp.html#Item) it does not inherit from QObject. The documentation also does not mention such a restriction. Can you link me to something that supports your point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177477/discussion-between-andrew-li-and-petert).

Comment: You may want to watch Herb Sutter's talk on leak freedom https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE

Comment: good assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some other type T2;
 in particular:

- when the expression is used as the argument when calling a function that is declared with T2 as parameter;
- when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects T2;
- when initializing a new object of type T2, including return statement in a function returning T2;
- when the expression is used in a switch statement (T2 is integral type);
- when the expression is used in an if statement or a loop (T2 is bool).

This helps you.
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/implicit_conversion_sequences.htm

Comment: It's usually better to provide links either to the Standard itself or to cppreference.com (than to the documtation of compiler vendors).

Comment: If this solves your issue, please vote my question, thanks.

Comment: I thought that using a non-bool object in an `if` or `while` counted as *explicit* conversion